# Noise-cancelling headphone concept

Tags: audio, noise, microphone

Inexpensive noise-cancelling headphones use a single microphone located in a little lump between the plug and the earphones. They seem to work fairly well for ambient noises, but not for handling noise or touching the headphones themselves.

I want to build a pair for myself, but with a mic inside each earpiece. They will be closed-back, with large drivers. The idea is to compare the source material with the sounds in the space closest to the ear.

#### idealized schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmXY8N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Obviously a simple resistive feedback network is wishful thinking. Or is it?

What are the phasing considerations for this environment? Not looking for a complete calculated answer, more like "do I need to continuously recalculate the feedback network based on different ear shape/position?"

Comment: If you want to cancel 200Hz from the environment, you would have to play it 180 deg out of phase at the same amplitude.  If you are doing this in the can, and using a second speaker for the source audio, it would be much easier than using a single speaker for the cancellation playback and the source playback.

Comment: One main problem you are going to see here is signal cancelling due to sound carrying from the speaker to the mic in the housing (lots of musical tones last longer than a tenth of a millisecond). If you want to get it perfect you need to tweak the delay and cancellation feedback to your design, I suppose by using the audio signal in your negative feedback as well you can compensate. Wolfson Audio does exactly this with a thoroughly researched DSP chip in a little box on the cord (Digital Silence, approx $80). Also think about the fact handling noise travels through the housing, not the speaker

Comment: Sorry for being so short, but I thought that would be better put in a comment. I like the idea of trying to do this, I'm just telling you what I know. If I had the time to I would offer to help figure out a working fully analog, because it sounds cool :-).

Comment: There's an "instructable" that looks somewhat better than average (which isn't saying much) on this, some dude did a class project using a solderless breadboard and a few op-amps per side. No quantitative figures at all on reduction and it is not claimed to reduce noise above 1kHz. See [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Analog-Noise-Cancelling-Headphones/). I think if I was attempting this I'd go the DSP route with an eval board.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, any idea why the all pass is in that instructable? (45 degree @ ~6kHz if I punched the right #'s) I would of thought invert all with a LP filter.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Wouldn't the roll off present a problem with LP?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, yeah.. LP and then all pass to undo LP phase shift.  (I'm reminded of an SED thread.)  Filtering without a phase shift seems to violate the Kramer's Kronig relations.